# An explode() function that ignores characters inside quotes?

Tags: php, string

Does somebody know a quick and easy `explode()` like function that can ignore splitter characters that are enclosed in a pair of arbitrary characters (e.g. quotes)?

Example:

```
my_explode(
  "/", 
  "This is/a string/that should be/exploded.//But 'not/here',/and 'not/here'"
);
```

should result in an array with the following members:

```
This is
a string 
that should be 
exploded.

But 'not/here', 
and 'not/here'
```

the fact that the characters are wrapped in single quotes would spare them from being splitters.

Bonus points for a solution that can deal with *two* wrapper characters

```
(not/here)
```

A native PHP solution would be preferred, but I don't think such a thing exists!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP explode the string, but treat words in quotes as a single word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202435/php-explode-the-string-but-treat-words-in-quotes-as-a-single-word)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)`($str, '/')`

There's a recipe for <5.3 on the linked page.

Comment: So then pass a different character as an enclosure.

Comment: doesnt matter. It returns `Array
(
    [0] => This is
    [1] => a string
    [2] => that should be
    [3] => exploded.
    [4] => 
    [5] => But 'not
    [6] => here',
    [7] => and 'not
    [8] => here'
)
`

Comment: Smells like a PHP bug to me then.

Comment: `str_getcsv` only acknowledges an enclosure character that occurs at the start of a split section (i.e. at the start of a string or right after a delimiter).  Not a bug (it handles CSV correctly), but no good for this question.

Comment: str_getcsv($str,'/',"'");  3rd param is enclosure.

Answer (score 5):

This is near-impossible with `preg_split`, because you can't tell from the middle of the string whether you're between quotes or not.  However, `preg_match_all` can do the job.

Simple solution for a single type of quote:

```
function quoted_explode($subject, $delimiter = ',', $quote = '\'') {
    $regex = "(?:[^$delimiter$quote]|[$quote][^$quote]*[$quote])+";
    preg_match_all('/'.str_replace('/', '\\/', $regex).'/', $subject, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

That function will have all kinds of problems if you pass it certain special characters (\^-], according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), so you'll need to escape those.  Here's a general solution that escapes special regex characters and can track multiple kinds of quotes separately:

```
function regex_escape($subject) {
    return str_replace(array('\\', '^', '-', ']'), array('\\\\', '\\^', '\\-', '\\]'), $subject);
}

function quoted_explode($subject, $delimiters = ',', $quotes = '\'') {
    $clauses[] = '[^'.regex_escape($delimiters.$quotes).']';
    foreach(str_split($quotes) as $quote) {
        $quote = regex_escape($quote);
        $clauses[] = "[$quote][^$quote]*[$quote]";
    }
    $regex = '(?:'.implode('|', $clauses).')+';
    preg_match_all('/'.str_replace('/', '\\/', $regex).'/', $subject, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

(Note that I keep all of the variables between square brackets to minimize what needs escaping - outside of square brackets, there are about twice as many special characters.)

If you wanted to use ] as a quote, then you probably wanted to use [ as the corresponding quote, but I'll leave adding that functionality as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: Edge case: If the quotes aren't balanced, this function will discard enough of them to make them balanced.

Comment: I just found out about the `preg_quote` function - that's probably a better way to escape characters in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Something very near with preg_split : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#92632

It handles multiple wrapper characters AND multiple delimiter characters.

Comment: Cheers @greg0ire, this looks good but still needs a little work. I'll try changing it to my needs with my feeble knowledge of Regexes.