# Split string by delimiter ignoring delimiter inside quotes

Tags: php

string from the file i'm importing: `1,2,3,"a","b","c","1,2,3,4,5",6,7`

desired output would be an array split by the comma but ignoring any comma that falls between double quotes.

```
[0] = 1;
[1] = 2;
[2] = 3;
[4] = "a";
[5] = "b";
[6] = "c";
[7] = "1,2,3,4,5";
[8] = 6;
[9] = 7;
```

Needs to work with PHP 5.2 and below. I know the fget_csv function allows for this in PHP 5.3 but its not an option unfortunately.

Searched fairly extensively and so far no solutions for this that I can find. Any ideas?

Comment: fgetcsv() is available since PHP 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An explode() function that ignores characters inside quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264775/an-explode-function-that-ignores-characters-inside-quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do csv in PHP < 5.3:

```
$lines = array();
if (($handle = fopen('file.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $lines[] = $line;
 }
    fclose($handle);
}
print_r($lines);

/* output:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => a
            [4] => b
            [5] => c
            [6] => 1,2,3,4,5
            [7] => 6
            [8] => 7
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. I was trying to use an explode which was messing things up. Thanks!