# Split text, but not if there are quotes

Tags: php, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP explode terms in to array, retain quoted text as single array item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136277/php-explode-terms-in-to-array-retain-quoted-text-as-single-array-item)

I want to convert this text

```
Hello this is "a test"
```

to an array, so that it looks like this:

```
Hello
this
is
"a test"
```

I used the php function explode

```
$words = explode(' ', $text);
```

But the problem is that it certainly ignores the quotes. How can I adjust the explode function, so that it behaves in the described way? Or should I use regex instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136277/php-explode-terms-in-to-array-retain-quoted-text-as-single-array-item?rq=1 this seems to be a same sort of exploding.