# PHP parse_str() function allowing passing shorthand array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing, configuration

We are accepting strings from templates to a markup engine, which allows for configuration to be passed in a "simple" form.

The engine parses the strings via PHP, using an adapted version of the parse_str() function - so we can parse any combination of the strings below:

```
config=posts_per_page:"5",default:"No questions yet -- once created they will appear here."&markup->template="{{ questions }}"
```

gives:

```
Array(
[config] => Array
    (
        [posts_per_page] => 5
        [default] => No questions yet -- once created they will appear here.
    )

[markup] => Array
    (
        [template] => {{ questions }}
    )
)
```

OR:

```
config->default=all:"<p class='ml-3'>No members here yet...</p>"
```

To Get:

```
Array 
[config] => Array
    (
        [default] => Array
            (
                [all] => <p class='ml-3'>No members here yet...</p>
            )

    )
)
```

Another:

```
config=>handle:"medium"
```

Returns:

```
Array (
[config] => Array
    (
        [>handle] => medium
    )
)
```

Strings can be passed with spaces ( and multi-line spaces ) and string parameters should be passed between "double quotes" to preserve natural spacing - we run the following preg_replace on the string before it is passed to the parse_str method:

```
// strip white spaces from data that is not passed inside double quotes ( "data" ) ##
$string = preg_replace( '~"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~', "", $string );
```

So far, so good - until we try to pass a "delimiter" inside a string value, then it is treated literally - for example the following string returns a corrupt array:

```
config=posts_per_page:"5",default:"No questions yet -- once created, they will appear here."&markup->template="{{ questions }}"
```

Returns the following array:

```
Array (
[config] => Array
    (
        [posts_per_page] => 5
        [default] => No questions yet -- once created
        [ they will appear here."] => 
    )

[markup] => Array
    (
        [template] => {{ questions }}
    )
)
```

The "," was treated literally and the string was broken into an extra array part.

One simple solution is to create delimiters and operators with a lower chance of conflicting with string values - for example changing "," to "@@@" - but one important part of the markup used is that it is easy to write and read - it's intended use-case is for front-end developers to pass simple arguments to the template parser - this is one reason we have tried to avoid JSON - which is of course a good fit in terms of passing data, but it's hard to read and write - of course, that statement is subjective and open to opinion :)

Here is the parse_str method:

```
public static function parse_str( $string = null ) {

    // h::log($string);

    // delimiters ##
    $operator_assign = '=';
    $operator_array = '->';
    $delimiter_key = ':';
    $delimiter_and_property = ',';
    $delimiter_and_key = '&';

    // check for "=" delimiter ##
    if( false === strpos( $string, $operator_assign ) ){

        h::log( 'e:>Passed string format does not include asssignment operator "'.$operator_assign.'" -- '.$string );

        return false;

    }

    # result array
    $array = [];
  
    # split on outer delimiter
    $pairs = explode( $delimiter_and_key, $string );
  
    # loop through each pair
    foreach ( $pairs as $i ) {

        # split into name and value
        list( $key, $value ) = explode( $operator_assign, $i, 2 );

        // what about array values ##
        // example -- sm:medium, lg:large
        if( false !== strpos( $value, $delimiter_key ) ){

            // temp array ##
            $value_array = [];  

            // split value into an array at "," ##
            $value_pairs = explode( $delimiter_and_property, $value );

            // h::log( $value_pairs );

            # loop through each pair
            foreach ( $value_pairs as $v_pair ) {

                // h::log( $v_pair ); // 'sm:medium'

                # split into name and value
                list( $value_key, $value_value ) = explode( $delimiter_key, $v_pair, 2 );

                $value_array[ $value_key ] = $value_value;

            }

            // check if we have an array ##
            if ( is_array( $value_array ) ){

                $value = $value_array;

            }

        }
     
        // $key might be in part__part format, so check ##
        if( false !== strpos( $key, $operator_array ) ){

            // explode, max 2 parts ##
            $md_key = explode( $operator_array, $key, 2 );

            # if name already exists
            if( isset( $array[ $md_key[0] ][ $md_key[1] ] ) ) {

                # stick multiple values into an array
                if( is_array( $array[ $md_key[0] ][ $md_key[1] ] ) ) {
                
                    $array[ $md_key[0] ][ $md_key[1] ][] = $value;
                
                } else {
                
                    $array[ $md_key[0] ][ $md_key[1] ] = array( $array[ $md_key[0] ][ $md_key[1] ], $value );
                
                }

            # otherwise, simply stick it in a scalar
            } else {

                $array[ $md_key[0] ][ $md_key[1] ] = $value;

            }

        } else {

            # if name already exists
            if( isset($array[$key]) ) {

                # stick multiple values into an array
                if( is_array($array[$key]) ) {
                
                    $array[$key][] = $value;
                
                } else {
                
                    $array[$key] = array($array[$key], $value);
                
                }

            # otherwise, simply stick it in a scalar
            } else {

                $array[$key] = $value;

            }
          
        }
    }

    // h::log( $array );
  
    # return result array
    return $array;

  }
```

I will try to skip splitting string between "double quotes" - probably via another regex, but perhaps there are other potential pitfalls waiting that might not make this approach viable long-term - any help glady accepted!

Comment: From what I could see, you should limit the `$value_pairs` to 2 items - `explode( $delimiter_and_property, $value, 2 )`.

Comment: Found a pretty solid solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264775/an-explode-function-that-ignores-characters-inside-quotes/13755505#13755505 - will try to apply it and test now.

Comment: Added as a potential answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution, is to change the following:

from:

```
$value_pairs = explode( $delimiter_and_property, $value );
```

to:

```
$value_pairs = self::quoted_explode( $value, $delimiter_and_property, '"' );
```

which calls a new method found on another SO answer ( linked in comment block ):

```
/**
 * Regex Escape values 
*/
public static function regex_escape( $subject ) {

    return str_replace( array( '\\', '^', '-', ']' ), array( '\\\\', '\\^', '\\-', '\\]' ), $subject );

}

/**
 * Explode string, while respecting delimiters
 * 
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264775/an-explode-function-that-ignores-characters-inside-quotes/13755505#13755505
*/
public static function quoted_explode( $subject, $delimiter = ',', $quotes = '\"' )
{
    $clauses[] = '[^'.self::regex_escape( $delimiter.$quotes ).']';

    foreach( str_split( $quotes) as $quote ) {

        $quote = self::regex_escape( $quote );
        $clauses[] = "[$quote][^$quote]*[$quote]";

    }

    $regex = '(?:'.implode('|', $clauses).')+';
    
    preg_match_all( '/'.str_replace('/', '\\/', $regex).'/', $subject, $matches );

    return $matches[0];

}
```