# Exploding string on space but not spaces in quotation marks

Tags: php, regex, filter, keyword, explode

I'm building a filter system with PHP. I need to give a priority on a text based on keywords matches. The filter has to recognize different types of keywords.

One of the types is normal words, `keyword1 keyword2`. This would filter on texts with both 'keyword1' and 'keyword2', no matter what order of whether they occur consecutively in the text or not.

An other type is a precise combination of words, `"keyword1 keyword2"`. This would give priority to articles with the exact combination "keyword1 keyword2".

There are other types but they aren't relevant here.

Keyword types may be combined, so `keyword1 "keyword2 keyword3"` is valid and would search for articles with both "keyword1" and the exact combination "keyword2 keyword3".

For the first type, I can use an `explode(' ', $keywords)` to get the keywords in an array. However, this would mess up with `keyword1 "keyword2 keyword3"`, because the text in the quotation marks would get separated as well.

So I need a function that separates the keywords, but doesn't separate the text in quotation marks. Is there a function that can do that? If not, is a regex the way to go?

Comment: Yes, regex could do what you want. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MCL I can write a regex, but I would like to know if there's a built-in function to do this. I don't ask you to write the regex, no `send-me-teh-codez` ;)

Comment: You can write your own parser, or make a match with regex. (I wouldn't recommend explode)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2202489/1282023).

Comment: Yes, duplicate of [PHP explode the string, but treat words in quotes as a single word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202435/php-explode-the-string-but-treat-words-in-quotes-as-a-single-word) - sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
$string = 'test1 test2 "test3 test4"';
preg_match_all('/\"[\s\S]+\")|([\S]+)/ism', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Alternatively, you could try using [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason (performance?) I would use the regex instead of str_getcsv?

Comment: Not really sure, I haven't tested the performance unfortunately, however you might get better long-term performance using `str_getcsv()` , however I think its mainly just preference

Comment: There's a missing `(`. Also, had to modify this to work with multiple strings in quotes like this: `preg_match_all('/(\"[\s\S]+?\")|(\'[\s\S]+?\')|([\S]+)/', $string, $matches);`