# How to convert argument list-style string to array of arguments in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to convert such string:

```
Zeroth "First" "Sec ond" "Th\"ird" Four th Six'th 'Seventh'
```

To array:

```
[0] => Zeroth
[1] => First
[2] => Sec ond
[3] => Thi"ird
[4] => Four
[5] => th
[6] => Six'th
[7] => 'Seventh'
```

Function should be fast and take care of double-quotes only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP explode the string, but treat words in quotes as a single word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202435/php-explode-the-string-but-treat-words-in-quotes-as-a-single-word)

Comment: `$myArray = str_getcsv($myString, ' ');`