# How can I explode a string into an array by space, but preserve quoted words?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, explode

Given the string `abc "def ghi"`, how can I return the array:

```
[0] => abc
[1] => def ghi
```

Other examples:

```
abc "def ghi"   =>   ['abc','def ghi']
abc def         =>   ['abc','def']
```

Comment: You even tagged it with `explode`, so where is the problem ?

Comment: Explode doesn't work. But I found str_getcsv() which let's me accomplish the same, preserving quotes.

Comment: Why doesn't `explode('"', $str);` not work for you ?

Comment: Because I would also want `abc def` to return array ['abc','def']

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202435/php-explode-the-string-but-treat-words-in-quotes-as-a-single-word

Comment: Good find @OIS. Interesting that the accepted answer uses preg_match_all(), but str_getcsv() seems easier.

Comment: @Ryan the accepted answer is not always the best, correct or best suitted for your use case. :) But questions should not be duplicated anyway. - The question is just after PHP5.3 when str_getcsv() was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

[str_getcsv()](http://php.net/str_getcsv)

```
$str = 'abc "def ghi"';
$arr = str_getcsv($str, ' ', '"');
print_r($arr);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def ghi
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$s = 'abc "def ghi"';
preg_match_all('/(?>"[^"]*"|\S+)/', $s, $m);

print_r($m[0]);
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => "def ghi"
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an advantage of using preg_match_all() rather than str_getcsv()?

Comment: It another alternative. To be honest I haven't performed any performance tests but my feeling is that `preg_match_all` might perform better.