# Split string on spaces except words in quotes

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like

```
$string = 'Some of "this string is" in quotes';
```

I want to get an array of all the words in the string which I can get by doing

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
```

However I don't want to split up the words in quotes so ideally the end array will be

```
array ('Some', 'of', '"this string is"', 'in', 'quotes');
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
$string = 'Some of "this string is" in quotes';
$arr = preg_split('/("[^"]*")|\h+/', $string, -1, 
                   PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r ( $arr );
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some
    [1] => of
    [2] => "this string is"
    [3] => in
    [4] => quotes
)
```

**RegEx Breakup**

```
("[^"]*")    # match quoted text and group it so that it can be used in output using
             # PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE option
|            # regex alteration
\h+          # match 1 or more horizontal whitespace
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really helped.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it this way, you can do it in another way aka matching. It will be a lot more easier to match than to split.

So use the regex: `/[^\s]+|".*?"/` in conjuction with `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get values by match, not by split, with regex:

```
/"[^"]+"|\w+/g
```

whis will match:

- `"[^"]+"` - characters between quote signs ",
- `\w+` - sets of word characters (A-Za-z_0-9),

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hB3mM5/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
/("[^"]*")|(\S+)/g
```

And you can use substitution `$2`

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/tF1mK1/1)