# PHP explode the string, but treat words in quotes as a single word and ignore brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, quotes, brackets

I am using the solution from [2202435](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202489/7567785). But when I add brackets to the string, it doesn't give the right result in the array.

```
 $text = 'Lorem ipsum ("dolor sit amet") consectetur "adipiscing \\"elit" dolor';
preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The above code produces

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem
            [1] => ipsum
            [2] => ("dolor
            [3] => sit
            [4] => amet")
            [5] => consectetur
            [6] => "adipiscing \"elit"
            [7] => dolor
        )

)
```

But the result I am looking for is

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem
            [1] => ipsum
            [2] => (
            [3] => "dolor sit amet"
            [4] => )
            [5] => consectetur
            [6] => "adipiscing \"elit"
            [7] => dolor
        )

)
```

I am able to achieve the above result, if I include a space after '( ' and before ' )'.

Please advise the correct regex expression that would allow me to keep the brackets seperate (with explanation if possible).

Thank you.

Comment: The reason is that the regex you use is meant to keep standalone `"` in the matches. Maybe `'/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|[^\s"]+/'` will help you.

Comment: Are you sure the unescaped double quotes are always paired in your input?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, Your solution works. As for the input, yes the double quotes always need to be paired as it is part of a search string to query the database.

Is it possible to include words in single quotes as a single word along with double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the regex you use is meant to keep standalone `"` in the matches.

If you are sure the unescaped double quotes are always paired in your input, use

```
'/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|[^\s"]+/'
                        ^^^^^^
```

Exclude the `"` from `\S` by turning it into a negative character class `[^\s]` and add the double quote inside.

To include single quoted substrings, you may use

```
'~"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\'(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\'])*\'|[^\s"\']+~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f1a43c/3) and a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/wW3RQ0):

```
$re = '~"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\'(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\'])*\'|[^\s"\']+~';
$str = 'Lorem ipsum ("dolor sit amet") consectetur "adipiscing \\"elit" dolor \'something  \\\'here\'';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
// => Array ( [0] => Lorem [1] => ipsum [2] => ( [3] => "dolor sit amet" [4] => )
//   [5] => consectetur [6] => "adipiscing \"elit" [7] => dolor [8] => 'something  \'here' )
```

Comment: This works, but I am not sure how to escape the string  \'apple\\\'s\' ?

Comment: What do you mean by escape it? Use inside PHP code as a string literal? `'apple\'s'` should be defined as `$s = "'apple\\'s'";`

Comment: I mean if i use addslashes("'apple's'"); this will basically return \'apple\'s\'. Since the value is from posted variable

Comment: Yes, [it will](https://ideone.com/B90Yc6), so what is the problem? Do you want to say you still need to match "wild" quotes?

Comment: If I use try to run this thru the previous solution https://ideone.com/PvsKtB , the result should be
Array
(
    [0] => 'apple\'s'
   
).

Comment: BTW, the string has no balanced quotes. It is just not possible to handle this kind of a string with regex. You cannot tell a `\'` you want to remove from another `\'` you want to keep.

Comment: Ahh! I see, well the best solution is then to force the user to use double quotes as before and ignore the single quotes in pairs... thank you so much