# R: Explode string but keep quoted text as a single word

Tags: r, regex, stringi

I encountered this question:
[PHP explode the string, but treat words in quotes as a single word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202435/php-explode-the-string-but-treat-words-in-quotes-as-a-single-word)

and similar dealing with using Regex to explode words in a sentence, separated by a space, but keeping quoted text intact (as a single word).

I would like to do the same in R. I have attempted to copy-paste the regular expression into `stri_split` in the stringi package as well as `strsplit` in base R, but as I suspect the regular expression uses a format R does not recognize. The error is:

> Error: '\S' is an unrecognized escape in character string...

The desired output would be:

```
mystr <- '"preceded by itself in quotation marks forms a complete sentence" preceded by itself in quotation marks forms a complete sentence'

myfoo(mystr)

[1] "preceded by itself in quotation marks forms a complete sentence" "preceded" "by" "itself" "in" "quotation" "marks" "forms" "a" "complete" "sentence"
```

Trying: `strsplit(mystr, '/"(?:\\\\.|(?!").)*%22|\\S+/')` gives:

```
Error in strsplit(mystr, "/\"(?:\\\\.|(?!\").)*%22|\\S+/") : 
  invalid regular expression '/"(?:\\.|(?!").)*%22|\S+/', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

Comment: Try `\\S` (as for any backslash character for a regex in R)

Comment: Where is the regular expression that you tried? Why is your code not in this question?

Comment: [`"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/rsbF5i/1)? *Also works with escaped double quotes*

Comment: @ctwheels, your suggested regex provides *exactly the same error* as the OP. It also might be remedied by Tensibai's comment about backslashes.

Comment: ashkan, the regex you provided requires perl-like expressions, so if you use `strsplit(..., perl=TRUE)` then you no longer get the error. (It doesn't correctly parse the string the way you want, but it doesn't provide an error.)

Comment: @r2evans the OP updated the post. Doesn't mean my answer is incorrect, just means I wasn't presented with all the information to correctly answer the question. My answer does work and does not provide the *exact same error as the OP* assuming the OP properly escapes my regex and uses `perl=TRUE`

Comment: Your suggested regex errors *exactly as the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/92d0f5f1-013e-4e40-bdb3-16f853459ed8/view-source)*. The correction is simple: adding the second backslash removes the error. R is non-standard in its use of double-backslashes, certainly. All I was saying was that you had not tested your suggestion in R *and it does not fix the error*.

Comment: After the edit it appears to be a well-formed question with an example and desired result.

Comment: @r2evans [I did test my answer in R and it does work](https://ideone.com/fyv37j). In any case, I think A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's answer is much nicer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple option would be to use `scan`:

```
> x <- scan(what = "", text = mystr)
Read 11 items
> x
 [1] "preceded by itself in quotation marks forms a complete sentence"
 [2] "preceded"                                                       
 [3] "by"                                                             
 [4] "itself"                                                         
 [5] "in"                                                             
 [6] "quotation"                                                      
 [7] "marks"                                                          
 [8] "forms"                                                          
 [9] "a"                                                              
[10] "complete"                                                       
[11] "sentence"
```