# PHP string explode on space, except when in quotes

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202435/php-explode-the-string-but-treat-words-in-quotes-as-a-single-word), however with one more twist.

I want to explode the following string:

```
title:"tab system" color:="blue" price:>10
```

into

```
array("title:\"tab system\"", "color:=\"blue\"", "price:>10")
```

Here's what I've tried so far from the above link:

```
$text = "title:\"tab system\" color:=\"blue\" price:>10";
preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which produces:

```
(
    [0] => title:"tab
    [1] => system"
    [2] => color:="blue"
    [3] => price:>10
)
```

and:

```
print_r(str_getcsv($text, ' '));
```

which produces the same thing.

These solutions don't work for me because as you can see, it's possible that the quotes may not start next to the delimiter (in this case, a space). Also, that's just one example of an input string, there could be many variations of it.

Comment: You could loop over each sign in the string. If you find a quote before a space, do nothing. If the quote is closed, and a space appears, cut out the pice of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sure thing, I've edited my question to include this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_split('~(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~s', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VD5OVE/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:\\{2})*` - zero or more double backslashes
- `"` - a quote
- `[^"\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `"` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - 0+ sequences of

  - `\\.` - any escape sequence
  - `[^"\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `"` and `\`
- `"` - a quote
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - skipping the match and proceeding to the next match from the current match end location
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces in any other contexts.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/hGEhGn):

```
$s = 'title:"tab system" color:="blue" price:>10';
print_r(preg_split('~(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~s', $s));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => title:"tab system"
    [1] => color:="blue"
    [2] => price:>10
)
```

Comment: Excellent! Pretty intense regex, it seems to serve the purpose well. Seems that I can accept this answer -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look for a whitespace with a double quote either before or after and then split on it:

```
$result = preg_split( "/((?<=\")\s)|(\s(?=\"))/" , $string );
```

`((?<=\")\s)` looks for `"[space]` but does not select the `"`

`(\s(?=\"))` looks for `[space]"` but does not select the `"`

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => title:"tab system"
    [1] => color:="blue"
    [2] => price:>10
)
```

Comment: You need to use regex delimiters. Also, it will fail in a lot of cases, e.g. [`title:"tab \" system" color:="blue" price:>10`](https://regex101.com/r/lHfCTl/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Forgot the delimiters, corrected. OP's example  has no escaped quotes, so didn't take them into account.

Comment: I think OP would not have tried a regex that supports escaped sequences in the first place if there was no such requirement.